# sharepoint website open very slow after change server location?

Tags: sharepoint

I am new in share point. I just made some static site and host it on server, its was working fine. due to some reason I change my server location now this site is responding very slow. I did not get any root cause why its happening, even there is 5 more share point sites all are working very slow. May be there is some configuration problem please help me to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like IIS is rebuilding the cache. This happens whenever the server is rebooted, or sharepoint is loaded in a new/different web server. Typically the speed increases after a few minutes as everything gets cached.

Answer (score 0):

What @marten said is correct.. its takes time for distributed cache service to kick in for new server. also check if there is any app pool/IIS recycling schedule is applied on new server.